# Использование CMS или создание сайта вручную?

Tags: cms

Я сам никогда не использовал эти системы. Стоит ли начать? И в чем их плюсы/минусы по сравнению с созданием вручную?

Comment: Плюс в том, что сэкономит кучу времени!! А так я в них ниче плохого не вижу. Сам использую ДЛЕ. Правда я его переписал на 40%.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай - если вы не видите ничего плохого - зачем тогда переписывал?.. =)

По сабжу - все зависит от задачи и цели, единственно правильного ответа здесь нет и быть не может.

С точки зрения перспектив работы программиста - лучше и не начинать :D Мб чуть тяжелее будет найти нормальную работу, зато не будете потом иметь дела со всем этим г....м. Да и, собственно, писать кода станете намного меньше, в основном будете править готовые плагины, писать свои, кривиться от вида исходного кода и поражаться тому бреду который там написан(не все бред - но его достаточно :D) и вылавливать баги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Советую обратить ваше внимание на WordPress. Удобный и понятный интерфейс, большое количество плагинов (добавляют доп. функционал сайту) и тем (и их легкое последующее редактирование под свои нужды). В общем начинайте с WordPress!

Answer (score 2):

Пишите сами, бесценный опыт.

Comment: Это уж точно. +1))